# Porting a class from MFC to a C++ Console Application . Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sockets, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to port a certain functionality from an MFC based application. Apparently I have no experience with MFC . The class of my interest inherits from CAsyncSocket. When looking that class up on MSDN , it states that the class is derived from `afxsock.h` . When I added that to my console application code I got the following error message which was

```
Error   1   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h
```

Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use any MFC stuff you need to link your program with MFC. the easiest way to do this is via the project properties. Open your project properties and go to "General". Select there "Use of MFC" either "use MFC in a static library" or "use MFC in a shared dll". Try to re-build your program. You may need to adjust some other options after that

Comment: Thanks could you tell me the difference between the two ?

Comment: if you select the latter you will need to distribute MFC with your app (via the installer). If you select the former option the size of the program binary will be bigger, but you will not need to distribute any dlls with it. It will work as is on any PC